# how to make dynamically stretchable table in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a basic html table, which contains cells that will scroll if they can not all fit in the alloted space.  I would like to allow the user to be able to stretch the table vertically by grabbing and stretching the bottom of the table.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [jQuery-UI resizeable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) interaction. This enables any DOM element to be resizeable and is very easy to use.

To only make it resizeable horizontally, modify the `handles` option to only enable the `north` and `south` edges:

```
foo.resizable({
    handles: 'n, s'
});​
```

Or for vertically:

```
foo.resizable({
    handles: 'e, w'
});​
```